# Form submit button is calling controller's index function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The author built a UPS scaffold and rails created the model as `up` instead of `ups`.  I've hacked some solutions in to make it work, but I can't get the create method to work when called from the new form.  Rails calls the index function and no new object is created.

**ups_controller.rb**

```
def create
    @up = Ups.new(params[:up])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @up.save
        format.html { redirect_to @up, notice: 'Up was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @up, status: :created, location: @up }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @up.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

def new
  @up = Ups.new

   respond_to do |format|
     format.html # new.html.erb
     format.json { render json: @up }
   end
end
```

**ups/form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@up) do |f| %>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field :name %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>attr</th>
            <td><%= f.select :attr_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Attr.order(:name).where(:major => true).all, "id", "name", @up.attr_id) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Action</th>     
            <td><%= f.submit "Submit New UPS" %></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
  resources :ups

  match 'ups/create' => 'ups#create'
  match 'ups/index' => 'ups#index'
  match 'pdus/link_all_ups' => 'pdus#link_all_ups'
```

**Here is the button that calls the new method of the ups_controller:**

```
<%= link_to 'Enter New UPS', new_ups_path, :class => "btn btn-success pull-right" %>
```

**rake routes**

```
                                 ups GET    /ups(.:format)                                          ups#index
                                     POST   /ups(.:format)                                          ups#create
                              new_up GET    /ups/new(.:format)                                      ups#new
                             edit_up GET    /ups/:id/edit(.:format)                                 ups#edit
                                  up GET    /ups/:id(.:format)                                      ups#show
                                     PUT    /ups/:id(.:format)                                      ups#update
                                     DELETE /ups/:id(.:format)                                      ups#destroy
                           ups_index        /ups/index(.:format)                                    ups#index
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Could you include the code from your controller that is called before the form is rendered?

Comment: Why would you do `match 'ups/create' => 'ups#create'` since you've already got `resources :ups`? Ref: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web

Comment: @Andy, added the code you asked for.

Comment: @amree, I was just trying that because nothing else seemed to work.

Comment: @JoeEssey: Weird, why Rails calls the index action, it should've called the show or render the new action. Can you post your `rake routes` output?

Comment: @amree, routes output posted above

Comment: Based on your routes, there's no `new_ups_path` available (which you used in `link_to`), something is off there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also want to make sure rails is sending a Post request like this:

```
<%= form_for @up, :url=> ups_path, :method => :post do |f| %>
```

My guess is that your url is correct but rails in sending it as a get instead of a post.  As you can see from your routes, the index and create action both have the same url and the only difference is the get/post.

```
ups GET    /ups(.:format)    ups#index

    POST   /ups(.:format)    ups#create
```

Comment: `<%= form_for(@up), :url => up_path, :method => :post do |f| %>` is giving me the following error: `syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting keyword_end`

Comment: Ahh my mistake, the parenthesis must be deleted, I have edited my answer.

Comment: Or the parenthesis should wrap all parameters... `<%= form_for(@up, url: ups_path, method: :post) do |f| %>`

Comment: @Josh, this is amazing... Now it's telling me the validation is failing becuase the fields are blank.  It's passing `:ups => { :name => "Name", :attr2 => "3" }` to the `ups_controller`

Comment: In your controller you have this line: `@up = Ups.new(params[:up])` but rails is passing a hash called `ups` so change the line to `@up = Ups.new(params[:ups])` and you should be in good shape.